# $_POST vs. $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'

Tags: php

Some guy called one of my Snipplr submissions "crap" because I used `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` instead of `if ($_POST)`

Checking the request method seems more correct to me because that's what I really want to do. Is there some operational difference between the two or is this just a code clarity issue?

Comment: @vinkoVrsalovic especially since as <gnud> mentions in his answer they are not the same and ($POST) is a sort of "hack" in that your check if an array, that only is present during a POST request, exists. Also the request method can be used in other cases like GET.

Comment: You should use `===` instead of `==` here as `0 == 'POST'`.

Comment: $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] may contain "POST" for HTTP GET requests on some PHP+Apache2 installations. Like mine. And this is how I got here.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan If that's true (which I don't believe it is), it's a grossly serious bug. Can you provide a link to a PHP or Apache bug report? Steps to reproduce? As it is, I just don't believe you.

Comment: @dave1010 Why would `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` ever be the number `0`? As far as I know, that's impossible.

Comment: @MarkAmery It's a matter of faith. Really.

Comment: Hmm first time I've ever come across this. Last team I worked on used `if ( $_POST )` all over the place (though they were known to do lots of things incorrectly). I'm glad you asked this. I'm just 10 years late, hah.

Comment: I find it convenient to just place a value in a variable along with my post or just use the submit value. And whether it is or not is up for debate I suppose, but it FEELS safer, I've never found a need to do otherwise.

Comment: @MarkAmery Maybe if my code might be run in (or copied into) a different context (not in a web-server say), then maybe it could be possible for that to return 0 (or something that gets converted to 0). Honestly I think it's fairly unlikely that would happen if I ran this code in a context where 'REQUEST_METHOD' doesn't make sense, but I don't know; I haven't checked the docs. If I use a single extra keypress I don't have to check, or even **think** about whether I have to check if it's safe. I use `===` unless I have a specific reason to choose `==`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Well, they don't do the same thing, really.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains the request method (surprise).

`$_POST` contains any post data.

It's possible for a POST request to contain no POST data.

I check the request method — I actually never thought about testing the `$_POST` array. I check the required post fields, though. So an empty post request would give the user a lot of error messages - which makes sense to me.

Comment: Theoretically, it could be possible, that the request method is 'post' (lower- or even mixed case). Does PHP automatically sanitize this on GET and POST?

Comment: After a short test, my PHP 5.2 on WinXP obviously doesn't do it, so probably the request_method should be sanitized to uppercase only.

Comment: @Boldewyn No, it doesn't, but if the client sends you a request method of 'post' or 'Post' when they intend to perform a POST request then they're in violation of spec, since HTTP methods are case-sensitive according to spec and the spec only defines the POST method, not e.g. the post or Post or pOsT method. I go into more detail about this in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21511879/1709587. Whether or not you want to coerce the method to uppercase to handle spec-violating client code is your choice.

Comment: And since they're not the same thing, it makes sense that we might use them for different things -- type and request payload.  I wonder if this makes anyone barf: I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to figure out what we're doing, and I use $_REQUEST to access the payload, which maintains a little independence between the concepts (in other words, I rarely use $_POST or $_GET specifically).

Comment: @grantwparks That sounds like bad deal. $_GET and $_POST have more to do with where the data was transported. Consider: "curl -k  -L -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' --data-binary \@sample.csv 'test-script.php?test=12345'"  The value "test" populates $_GET even though the method is POST.

Answer (score 47):

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` is the correct way, you can send a post request without any post data.

Comment: so remember to use: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Answer (score 23):

I used to check `$_POST` until I got into a trouble with larger POST data and uploaded files. There are configuration directives `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` - if any of them is exceeded, `$_POST` array is not populated.

So the "safe way" is to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. You still have to use `isset()` on every `$_POST` variable though, and it does not matter, whether you check or don't check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Answer (score 15):

If your application needs to react on request of type post, use this:

```
if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST') { // if form submitted with post method
    // validate request, 
    // manage post request differently, 
    // log or don't log request,
    // redirect to avoid resubmition on F5 etc
}
```

If your application needs to react on any data received through post request, use this:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {  // if received any post data
   // process $_POST values, 
   // save data to DB,
   // ... 
}

if(!empty($_FILES)) { // if received any "post" files
   // validate uploaded FILES
   // move to uploaded dir
   // ...
}
```

It is implementation specific, but you a going to use both, + $_FILES superglobal.

Answer (score 4):

They are both correct. Personally I prefer your approach better for its verbosity but it's really down to personal preference.

Off hand, running **`if($_POST)`** would not throw an error - the **`$_POST`** array exists regardless if the request was sent with `POST` headers. An empty array is cast to false in a boolean check.

Comment: maybe in 2009, but an empty array != false

Comment: You might have missed the word "cast". The statement inside of an "if" structure is cast to a boolean, and an empty array is thus cast to a boolean false. Even in 2020

Answer (score 4):

You can submit a form by hitting the enter key (i.e. without clicking the submit button) in most browsers but this does not necessarily send submit as a variable - so it is possible to submit an empty form i.e. `$_POST` will be  empty but the form will still have generated a http post request to the php page. In this case `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` is better.

Comment: In that case, `$_POST` would not be empty: it would be an array with empty values.

Answer (score 2):

As long as I may need to access my PHP scripts with more than one method, what I do actually is:

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],array("GET","POST","DELETE"))) {
// do wathever I do 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($this->method == 'POST' && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
        $this->method = 'DELETE';
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $this->method = 'PUT';
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected Header");
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer might be correct, it is not helpful without explanation! Please have a look at [answer]! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It checks whether the page has been called through POST (as opposed to GET, HEAD, etc).
When you type a URL in the menu bar, the page is called through GET. However, when you submit a form with method="post" the action page is called with POST.

Answer (score -3):

It's really a 6 of one, a half-dozen of the other situation.

The only possible argument against your approach is $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' may not be populated on certain web-servers/configuration, whereas the $_POST array will always exist in PHP4/PHP5 (and if it doesn't exist, you have bigger problems (-:)

Answer (score -18):

They both work the same way, but `$_POST` should be used as it is cleaner. You can add `isset()` to it to check it exists.

Comment: `$_POST` will always exist, though it may be empty (which is cast to boolean `false`). And what do you mean by "cleaner"?

Comment: maybe he meant that less characters are needed to type on the keyboard =P