# FormData no longer working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post

So my server is no longer accepting formData however if I call with a string with all the parameters concatenated it works. So this WAS working before and now its not. So I set up my formData object and pass it in to a function that generates an $http.post() object:

```
function HTTPClient($http, $rootScope, arguments){
    return $http.post($rootScope.URL, arguments,{
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
}
```

But when I call

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

I get

```
array(0)
```

Why isn't this working anymore? I suspect its a change in our backend (I'm not the main server person) can someone help, our website is suddenly nonfunctional.

Comment: because you are using `.get`, you need to be using `.post`

Comment: "I ordered a pepsi. you gave me pepsi. why is it pepsi? I wanted coke".

Comment: Woops, that was before I editted it, that method call isn't there.

Comment: Show how you are calling HTTPClient

Comment: var memberClubClient = HTTPClient($http, $rootScope, fd);
    memberClubClient.success(function(data) {....}
    .error(function(data){...});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after completely botching my post here most people reasonably (accurately?) assumed I was an idiot and answered as such. I was able to find the issue however, our server was upgraded to HTTPS without my knowledge, and our server administrator didn't feel inclined to mention that when I asked "did you make any changes to the server?".

So if your client is HTTP and your server is HTTPS it'll reject form data!

Answer (score 1):

POST and GET are not the same thing :)

```
function HTTPClient($http, $rootScope, arguments){
return $http.post($rootScope.URL, arguments,{
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
}
```

this should do the job :) more about those two http requests:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: That method call isn't there, I miseditted the post.

Comment: you dont need that "method: POST" becuase, $http.post() does exactly this :)

Comment: The method call isn't there, I've fixed up the post to the actual code (I had been doing a bunch of fiddling around just before I posted this)

Comment: <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

require_once('../include_dao.php');
require_once('../include_dao_ext.php');
require_once('../controller/ServiceRequestHandler.php');

// All parameters sent in request
$params = array();
echo "website: " . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . "||";
echo "Type: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . "||";
echo "Func: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST["func"]). "||";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Retrieve all POST parameters
    var_dump($_POST);

This is all the code up to the var_dump

Comment: because your var_dump($_POST) equals "array(0)" it shows, that your formular data is empty. I think its not read correctly by the client, but i dont know until you post more of your code. plz edit your question to do so. maybe this could help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post