# HTML form values submit to PHP and query

Tags: php

I'm wondering if anyone has a spare set of eyes for a moment or two. The problem I see lies with my issets. It is ignoring the first initial isset($lastName) and seems to always choose isset($title). Also I should mention the values are being posted from a HTML form to ssearch against a surname or title in a DB.

My question is, can anyone help with the logic problem or is there another way of doing so ? I know its prone to SQL injection too, however it's on a local DB and I'll be looking into this closely quite soon. If anyone can make suggestions I am definitely interested to hear them.

As per suggestion the HTML form.

```
<form name="lookup" method="post" action="searchEmployeeList.php" autocomplete="off">
<fieldset>
    <p>Conduct a search</p>
    <table width="600">
        <tr>
            <td width="150">Surname:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder="Employees surname">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150">Title:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder="Job role">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <!--Blank row-->
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search now">

                <input type="submit" name="show_all" value="Show all">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>

 if (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {

 include 'DBConDetails.php';

 if (isset($lastName)) {

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_data Where last_name = '".$_POST['lastName'].
     "'";
 }
 if (isset($_POST['title'])) {

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_data Where title = '".$_POST['title'].
     "'";
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 if ($result - > num_rows > 0) {

     echo "<table id = 'searchResults'> < tr >
         < td > ID < /td> < td > Name < /td> < td > Age < /td><td>Title</td > < td > Years of Service < /td> < td > Salary < /td> < /tr>";

     //multiple echos plainly for readability
     while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>' . $row["employee_id"] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row["first_name"] . ' ' . $row["last_name"] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row["age"] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row["title"] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row["yos"] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row["salary"] . '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';

     }
 } else {

     echo "I'm afraid we could not find any matches, try editing your criteria.";
 }
 echo "</table>";


}
```

If anyone should come across a similar problem in the future, the issue lay with both if statements being true, which lead to both executing and the latter overwriting the first `if()` statement. *Should have noticed that* !

Comment: suggestion? sure; post your HTML form to leave the guesswork out of it

Comment: If you enter LastName and Title it will always do the second `IF` which will overwrite the first!!!

Comment: @Bastiaan Your suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9976787 **is worse!** - *sigh.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Apologies, I just included it above a moment ago. Also disregard the two buttons as one displays all results as opposed to specific entries.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's exactly what's happening as both statements are true, any suggestions on another way of putting it ?

Comment: @morrisstu I posted something for you below and I'm not sure if you saw it or not.  I also made a few edits in the past 5 minutes. You will need to reload my answer to see the additional information I left in there. Do go over it in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're overwriting your first query/conditional statement.

What you're telling it to do is, *"if this is set, do this. If this is set, then do that".*

What I feel you're *probably* looking to do is to check if both are set then passing those variables in your query in one go.

Such as and using `!empty()` instead of `isset()`:

```
if (!empty($_POST['lastName']) && !empty($_POST['title']) ) {

    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_data 
            Where last_name = '" . $lastName . "' 
            AND title = '" . $title . "'";
}
```

If the goal here is to check for one **OR** the other (which looks to be the case), you can modify the above code to, and using the `OR` operator:

```
if (!empty($lastName) || !empty($title) ) {

    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_data 
            Where last_name = '" . $lastName . "' 
            OR title = '" . $title . "'";
}
```

and getting rid of:

```
if (isset($title)) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_data Where title = '" . $title . "'";
}
```

Sidenote: The `OR` - `||` operator can also be used in a PHP conditional statement. `&&` is `AND`; choose the one that is fitting for what you wish to achieve.

If my above throws you an error because of a character that MySQL is complaining about, such as apostrophes, then you will need to escape your data with [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Sidenote: If you're going to use the above, make sure you're connected to your database first, and placing `include 'DBConDetails.php';` as your first line above anything. It's usually good to be connected first.

Plus, your code is prone to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Plus, there is no opening PHP tag before `if (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {` statement; if that is your actual code.

It should read as

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {
...
```

---

Footnotes:

`DBConDetails.php` is unknown as to which MySQL API you're using. You need to use the same API from connection to querying. Different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

- Consult [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Check for errors against your query also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

If you want to seperate your submit buttons' actions

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search now">
<input type="submit" name="show_all" value="Show all">
```

You will need to use seperate conditional statements and using the related name attribute.

I.e.:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// do something, as in include other conditionals, code etc.
}
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['show_all'])) {
// do something, as in include other conditionals, code etc.
}
```

Comment: gone to make/have dinner. Ping me later

Comment: That solved the issue, while I did not use the !empty() it did give me the idea to edit the isset() and sql statement which did give me the results I wanted. I was looking to check one OR the other so you were correct in covering that guess also. I have the conditional statements based on the forms attributes. Also the closing PHP tag was included just below in the code, I apologise for that. Thanks a million for the extra material too, comprehensive as always.

Comment: @morrisstu  Glad to hear it. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be checking:

```
isset($_POST['lastName']);
```

instead of

```
isset($lastName);
```

As the latter would be set, but be equal to some undefined value (Maybe empty string?). The same applies to your title variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it is better to check on `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

See: [$_POST vs. $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post)

After that, you can check the `$_POST` variables with `isset` and maybe it can be helpful to check the variables with `strlen` too. When you use `strlen`, with `trim` you can remove the unnecessary spaces.

Example:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    if(isset($_POST['lastName']) && strlen(trim($_POST['lastName'])) > 0) {
        // Do some action
    }
}
?>
```