# echo my form values on php

Tags: php, html, forms

Am using the code below in order to print the values that am inserting on the boxes. However After I put the values and click submit nothing is printing out.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $name;
echo $email;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

About below I tried both cases because on the simple one $_POST['email'] I was getting a warning:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Warning:

> Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.2.

Comment: LoL. `Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly` - This is given by the stupid IDE. Ignore it please.

Comment: NetBeans IDE is not something that stops you working from using PHP. And using `$_POST` or any other super-globals is never a bad idea.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar so there is no security issue using this type of command?

Comment: Absolutely not. `:)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Although I agree this is related, but man, this is a bad dupe target! `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar why bad? The posted code is clear; what am I missing here? I've seen this countless times and closed countless times without any conflict of interest.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Eh, if you say so. `:D` But the comments are great. Firing a lot of things.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {...}` that will never happen and error reporting would have clearly thrown an undefined submit index notice. If people are then chased down a deep rabbit hole, is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Appreciate your austere(strict) style. I know that stack overflow has to deal with more difficult things and more discussable topics. However I think Stack Overflow has proffessionals who can reply and give an excellent explanation to a beginner. Related issue would never give me a clear solution in my mind.

Have a nice day

Comment: @ChristosMichael Stack's ways of dealing with obvious code is clear. "They" implemented those voting closures for a reason. This type of question has been asked more times than you could count each popcorn you eat and by many more bowlfulls than you know, which is why the question was closed based on that; "asked too many times". If we were to continually allow answers that solve it to be posted, the Q&A's would just keep piling up too much. In having this type of system, helps to lower that amount.

Comment: @ChristosMichael Just a final note: Using error reporting (something that nobody addressed *(till now)* ) is crucial during testing/development. Follow this link on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply that to your code. Yes, I agree that when someone gives a good explanation as to why code fails is important, however the duplicate (in its own right) also does that. *Quick tip:* When using a conditional `if{...}`, use an accompanied `else{...}`; which yours would have fallen into.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for you info and time

Comment: @ChristosMichael You're welcome.

Comment: What about:

    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
    }

    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is never set:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

Instead change it to:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
```

You don't have any elements matching `name="submit"`. Also, it is a bad practise to use `isset($_POST["submit"])` as many of us, won't name it.

If you want to check for specific things set, like in your case, you need to do:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

If still you wanna make your code work with the above set-up, kindly add a `name` and `value` here:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Is there a way to print out the values without an if case?

Comment: @ChristosMichael I have explained that as well. You just need to make sure that they are set before printing right? Else it will throw a Reference Error or Undefined Index error. It's always better to have a check before you print it out. Also, you can just echo using `echo @$_POST["name"]` so that you don't get the error. But please, don't use it often.

Comment: why not simply use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {` ?

Comment: @Hallur What if those values aren't passed?

Comment: why are they not passed??? if post is set, then the server request method is always post.. Also sorry, I meant instead of using count()

Comment: @Hallur What if, you are using a `checkbox`, if you aren't selecting it, it never gets passed.

Comment: if you send post data to the server, then the server will always detect that the server request method is post.. no matter what element is being submitted. if post is set, then request method = post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post

Comment: Maybe you aren't understanding what I'm trying to tell you. Don't count post, to check if post is set... doesn't make sense. specifcally referring to this part of your answer `count($_POST) > 0`

Comment: @Hallur Agreed with that part. Fine. I am saying, to check individual elements being set, I use the `isset`. That's fine right? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Correct.

Comment: @PraveenKumar So in order to use isset() I should but on the <input> a name and a value? I am just talking in general not only for this case

Comment: @ChristosMichael Better to check the request method, isset on the required inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML element with the attribute name 'submit' exists.

Replace `<input type="submit">` with `<input type="submit" name="submit">`.

Don't ever use `isset($_POST['submit'])` as it is considered to be a bad practice.

Instead you can use `!empty($_POST)`. Doing it this way is considered to be safe.

Comment: Hi Perumal, how is this different from my answer? Just curious to know.

Comment: To be precise, your answer is complicated than mine. The reason is, you have given everything in a single line, which makes congested to read. Just an advice.

Comment: As I suggested to the other answer, it is bad practice to not use server request_method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post

Comment: @PraveenKumar How about now? This is what you meant?

Comment: @Perumal93 Looks nice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: It's still wrong to use `!empty($_POST)`.. instead use `$_SEVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: While the developer knows that the request method is going to be POST, using $_POST alone is enough. If the developer thinks in the point of view suggesting that if he wants to make handling posted data flexible, he could go for the conditional code like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST)`.