# Why is REQUEST_METHOD == POST not ok to use?

Tags: php, sql

Why is REQUEST_METHOD == POST not ok to use? What would be a better way to write this code in PHP 7.0.0.?

```
<?php
$connection= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","root");
if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
// Kontrola připojení
if($connection === false){
    die("ERROR: Error conecting to database. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: You could use if(isset($_POST).

Comment: I'm not using `_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` myself but why it's not ok to use?

Comment: @Jonny Would `isset($_POST)` be false in some circumstances?

Comment: if isset checks if it is there so yes if it is not it returns false

Comment: @Jonny And when will a superglobal not be there?

Comment: Here's something you may can read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409351/post-vs-serverrequest-method-post